# Kernel debugging in visual studio: Watch window array length

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, kernel, watch

I'm using visual studio for kernel debugging. Yes, I know all the tutorials say to use WinDbg, but visual studio is actually spectacular now for Kernel debugging. It's a more recent development.

When I have a pointer in the watch window, assuming it is an array, I would like to see multiple items in its list at once as a drop down. Normally in Visual Studio you would add ",AMOUNT" after the pointer to get multiple items, but this does not work when in kernel debugging mode.

Is this option available?

[Edit] As requested, I have attached an example image. In the watch window I have included multiple attempts to access the data in the "ProcessPath" variable.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that it works well for general app's debugging like VC++/VC pointer? Can you share me a simple sample using one drive? How did you input the text in the watch window? Can you share me a screen shot?

Comment: I have attached the picture.

Comment: do you enable the "Use Native Compatibility Mode" or "Use Native Compatibility Mode" under Tools->Options->Debugging? Not the real kernel debugging expert, but I just meet the similar issue like the two Debugging options impact the debugging Watch Window. If still no help, please share a simple sample, so I could set up the Environment and repro this issue.

Comment: I could not find that option in the Debugging->General section. Did you mean to say "Use Native Compatibility Mode" twice? I am currently using 2013, is it a 2015 option? I've switched environments before for testing so could do so again. If you haven't done kernel debugging before, its a bit of a PITA to get set up and going. The easiest way would be to use the [hello world app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx) provided by Microsoft. Within it, all you'd have to do is create a char* variable for testing.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would have left a reason explaining why this is not a good question.  That could have helped the OP fix it, or the rest of us ask better questions.

Comment: Yes, that would have been very nice ~.~

Answer (score 3):

During Kernel Mode Debugging, Watch window appears to work through WinDBG expression evaluator. That is, it works pretty much the same as WinDBG's Watch window. Therefore, your question is not really Visual Studio related, but rather it boils down to WinDBG's watch.

This is why `,amount` syntax will result in showing `amount` as result - WinDBG treats `,` as "evaluate and discard", just like c++ does. This also explains why you prepend variables with `$!` which is WinDBG syntax for local variables.

While WinDBG supports quite a bit of c++ syntax, it will unfortunately fail to recognize c++ cast-to-array syntax such as `(char(*)[4])$!ProcessPath`  (by the way, this works when debugging a usermode target in in VS debugger).

I have not found a single way to cast to array in WinDBG. It seems the only workaround available is to add specific elements of array to watch, like

```
ProcessPath[0]
ProcessPath[1]
ProcessPath[2]
ProcessPath[3]
ProcessPath[4]
ProcessPath[5]
ProcessPath[6]
ProcessPath[7]
ProcessPath[8]
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'll give you an upvote for this, but can't really consider it a solution. Might as well give you the 50 points... since otherwise it will just disappear.